# integers to char implementation

Tags: c++, data-structures

I'm trying to implement a program where user inputs number/int and the program would output the matching char. I have thought of doing this using vectors to store data. I was wondering if there was a faster or better way to implement this?
DATA stored in text file with more numbers this is justexample.

```
{2300, V }
{2400, W }
{2500, X }
{2600, Y }
{2700, Z }
{2800, [ }
{2900, \ }

SAmple run:
input: 2300
output: V
```

Comment: Use: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_map/unordered_map/

Answer (score 1):

You can use `std::map` (internally a self-balanced binary search tree) which will give log(N) time complexty for retrieving an element, or `std::unordered_map` (internally a hash table) which will give constant time complexity for retrieving an element.

The example below is in `std::map`, but you can easily change it to `std::unordered_map`

```
int main() {
  map<int, char> m;
  m[2300] = 'V';
  m[2400] = 'W';
  .... //Populate, store the elements in the map

  int input;
  cin >> input; //input should be a value in the map otherwise you may get a empty char
  cout << m[input] << endl;
  return 0;
}
```